# Loading Assemblies from NuGet Packages

Tags: powershell, nuget-package, powershell-4.0

Sometimes in my PowerShell scripts, I need access to a specific DLL, using `Add-Type -AssemblyName`. However, the DLLs I need aren't always on the machine or in the GAC. For instance, I might want a quick script that uses Dapper to query a database. In these cases, I have been literally copying the DLLs along with the `ps1` file. I was wondering if this was common/a good idea and whether there was an existing extension that would load up NuGet packages, store then in a global or local folder and call `Add-Type -AssemblyName` automatically.

It'd be a lot like using `npm` or `pip` in Node.js or Python, respectively.

### Update

I did some research and there's nothing built-in to older versions of PowerShell. I made some progress trying to write one from scratch using the `nuget.exe`

```
&"$(Get-Location)/nuget.exe" install $packageName -Version $version -OutputDirectory "$(Get-Location)/packages" -NoCache -NoInteractive
```

This will download a given package/version under a "packages" folder in the current folder, along with any of its dependencies. However, it looks like it downloads every framework version, with no obvious way to tell which one to use for your given environment.

Otherwise, you could just loop through the results and call Add-Type:

```
Get-ChildItem .\packages\ -Recurse -Filter "*.dll" | % {
    try
    {
        Add-Type -Path $_.FullName
    }
    catch [System.Exception]
    {
    }
}
```

I tried using the `restore` command using a `project.json` file to see if I could control the framework version with no luck. This is just too hacky for me.

I'll check out @crownedjitter's suggestion of using PowerShell 5.

### Update

Using @crownedjitter's suggestion, I was able to eventually register the PackageManagement module with NuGet (see comments below). With the following command, I was able to reproduce what the `Nuget.exe` command above was doing:

```
Install-Package Dapper -Destination packages
```

Obviously, this is a lot shorter. Problem is it has the same limitation; it brings down every framework version of a package. If this includes .NET core, it brings down a good deal of the .NET core framework with it! There doesn't appear to be a way to specify a target framework (a.k.a, .NET 4.5.1 or below).

[image: Install-Package grabbing dependencies for all .NET frameworks]

I am wondering if there is a way to determine which NuGet package folder(s) to load the DLLs from based on PowerShell's current `$PSVersionTable.CLRVersion` field.

Comment: `Add-Type -Path`?

Comment: If the NuGet package was already on the machine, that would make it possible to point to the folder. I am more curious about a tool that downloads the actual NuGet package and does the `Add-Type` call on your behalf.

Answer (score 39):

[crownedjitter's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39261022/45375) is a good starting point, and Travis himself has provided additional pointers in comments, but let me try to **summarize** with respect to *Windows PowerShell* (whose latest and *last* version is 5.1.x) as well **as of [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) 7.4.0**:

*Update*: The **original answer**, reprinted in the section after this one, contains some useful general pointers, plus a link to the [feature suggestion on GitHub to integrate NuGet packages with `Add-Type`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6724), but **the `Install-Package` based method it shows ultimately falls short**, because it **doesn't account for *dependencies* of a package**, as
[BACON](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150605/bacon) points out:

> The one (not-so-trivial) step that's missing is loading any dependencies that may have been installed, too. Because [the Dependencies property doesn't contain enough information](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/370), it seems that would involve extracting the `.nuspec` file from the `.nupkg` file in the Source directory, reading the `<group>` for the appropriate framework, and loading those packages' assemblies.

The **following approach remedies this**, but note that it **first requires download and installation of the [.NET SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) with its `dotnet` CLI**:

- Create a folder for an auxiliary project to which the package will be added and change to it; e.g.:

  - `Set-Location (New-Item -Type Directory assemblies)`
- In that folder, create a dummy library project:

  - For *PowerShell (Core)*, to target the latest installed .NET (Core) SDK by default:

    - `dotnet new classlib`
  - For *Windows PowerShell* or to target a .NET 5+ *OS-specific* framework:

    - To target the highest [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) that is still .NET Framework-compatible:

      - `dotnet new classlib -f netstandard2.0`
    - To target a specific .NET Framework version *only* or a .NET 5+ [*OS-specific* framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#net-5-os-specific-tfms):

      - You'll have to *manually* edit the generated `.csproj` and update the `<TargetFramework>` element; e.g., to target the latest and last version, 4.8, use `<TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>`; to target .NET 6.0 with Windows-specific APIs, use 
        `<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>`
    - Targeting .NET Framework may require downloading a [developer pack](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks) first.
- Add a reference to the package of interest; e.g.:

  - `dotnet add package Dapper`
  - To reference a specific version, add `-v <version>`
- Publish the dummy project, which copies all required DLLs, including dependencies, into the publish folder:

  - `dotnet publish -c Release`
  - **Important**: The exact case (lower- vs. uppercase) of the `-c` argument determines the exact case of the corresponding output folder; to make sure your code works on case-sensitive filesystems too, notably on Linux, *make sure that you use the exact same case in the file paths referring to the output binaries*.
- Test that the package's main assembly can be loaded; e.g.:

  - `Add-Type -Path bin/Release/*/publish/Dapper.dll`
  - Verify that the package's types can be used; e.g.: `[Dapper.DbString]::new()`

Now you can either reference the main DLL directly from the auxiliary project, or you can copy all `bin/Release/*/publish/*.dll` files to a folder of your choice and reference it from there.

The following **sample script** shows a script that downloads the [Terminal.Gui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Terminal.Gui) package on demand, and creates the auxiliary project in an `assemblies` subfolder relative to the script's location.

```bash
$packageName = 'Terminal.Gui'
$assembly = "$packageName.dll"
# Set to @() to get the latest stable version.
$packageVersionArgs = '-v', '1.0.0-pre.4'

$projectFolder = 'assemblies' # Subfolder for the aux. project
$assemblyPath = "$PSScriptRoot/$projectFolder/bin/Release/*/publish/$assembly"
$literalAssemblyPath = Convert-Path -ErrorAction Ignore $assemblyPath

if ($literalAssemblyPath) {
  Write-Verbose -vb "Package '$packageName' already installed. Loading main assembly: $literalAssemblyPath"
  Add-Type -ErrorAction Stop -LiteralPath $literalAssemblyPath
}
else {

  Write-Verbose -vb "Installing package '$packageName'..."

  $null = Get-Command -ErrorAction Stop -CommandType Application dotnet

  Push-Location (New-Item -ErrorAction Stop -Type Directory "$PSScriptRoot/$projectFolder")

  $null = dotnet new classlib
  $null = dotnet add package $packageName @packageVersionArgs
  $null = dotnet publish -c Release
  
  Pop-Location

  Write-Verbose -vb "Loading main assembly: $assemblyPath"  
  Add-Type -ErrorAction Stop -Path $assemblyPath
}

# Instantiate a type from the package to verify that it was loaded.
"Listing property names of a [Terminal.Gui.Button] instance:"
[Terminal.Gui.Button]::new().psobject.Properties.Name
```

**Caveat**:

- Some packages have dependencies on *native libraries*, which `dotnet publish` places in the `runtimes` subfolder tree of the publish folder, in platform-specific subfolders such as `runtimes\win-x64\native`.
- In *Windows PowerShell*, `Add-Type -LiteralPath` (and its underlying .NET API method, [`[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom)) *does* find the platform-appropriate native library, but, curiously, it does *not* work as of *PowerShell (Core) 7.2.0-preview.9* - at least as observed with version 5.0.9 of the [`Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite) NuGet package.
- The *workaround* is to find the platform-appropriate native library in the `runtimes` subfolder tree and copy it *directly* into the publish folder. The install-on-demand `Add-NuGetType` helper function, discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69126680/45375), automates this process.

---

#### ORIGINAL ANSWER

- As stated, PowerShell v5+ - including PowerShell *Core* - comes with the `PackageManagement` module that is a meta package manager providing access to multiple repositories via *providers*; on-demand installation of this module is *may* be possible in v3 and v4 ([this download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51451) is labeled "March 2016 Preview", and it is the most recent I could find).

  - `Find-PackageProvider` lists all *available* providers.
  - `Get-PackageProvider` lists *installed* ones.
- It is the `nuget` provider that enables **installation of Nuget packages via `Install-Package`**, and there are **two potential hurdles**:

  - The `nuget` provider may not be installed.
  - It may be installed with an incorrect API URL that prevents `Find-Package` from returning results.

**Test if the `nuget` provider is installed**:

```bash
# If this fails, the provider isn't installed
Get-PackageProvider nuget
```

**If it *is* installed: Verify that the package source URI is correct:**

- Open an *elevated* PowerShell session.
- Run `Get-PackageSource`:

  - If you find a `Nugettest` source, remove it:

    - `Unregister-PackageSource Nugettest`
  - If the `Location` column for source `nuget.org` shows `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` (or something other than `ttps://www.nuget.org/api/v2`), update it:
  - `Set-PackageSource nuget.org -NewLocation https://www.nuget.org/api/v2 -Trusted`
  - **Caveat**: This may break the ability to browse NuGet packages in Visual Studio: see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet/issues/107

**If it is *not* installed: Install the provider from scratch**:

- Open an *elevated* PowerShell session.
- Run the following commands:

  ```bash
  Install-PackageProvider nuget
  Register-PackageSource -ProviderName nuget -name nuget.org -Location https://www.nuget.org/api/v2 -Trusted
  ```

---

**After completing the above steps, discovery (e.g., `Find-Package Dapper`) and installation (e.g., `Install-Package Dapper`) of NuGet packages should succeed.**

By default, `Install-Package` installs in the `AllUsers` scope, which requires elevation, but you can opt into installing in the context of the current user only with `-Scope CurrentUser`.

---

***Using* a downloaded NuGet package**:

Note: See [GitHub issue #6724](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6724), which suggests making the use of NuGet packages in PowerShell easier by extending `Add-Type`, which would obviate the need for all subsequent steps, which are still needed as of PowerShell Core 7.3.2.

- As demonstrated in the question, **you need to manually load the package's assemblies into your PowerShell session with `Add-Type -Path <assembly-file-path>`**; however, in the era of .NET Core, packages may have DLLs for different .NET environments, so **you cannot always blindly load *all* `*.dll` files in the package folder**:
- In order to discover the file-system location of a downloaded package, query the `.Source` property of the relevant object returned by `Get-Package`:

  ```bash
  (Get-Package Dapper).Source
  ```
- To **see the full paths of all DLLs inside the package**, run the following:

  ```bash
  (Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dll -Recurse (Split-Path (Get-Package Dapper).Source)).FullName
  ```
- Looking at the full DLL paths should tell you which DLL(s) are the right ones to load for your environment; using the example of the `Dapper` package:

  ```bash
  C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\Dapper.1.50.4\lib\net451\Dapper.dll
  C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\Dapper.1.50.4\lib\netstandard1.3\Dapper.dll
  C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\NuGet\Packages\Dapper.1.50.4\lib\netstandard2.0\Dapper.dll
  ```
- Given that ***.NET Standard* DLLs run on *all* .NET platforms**, however, you can programmatically look for the (latest) such DLLs and load them:

  ```bash
  (Get-Item (Join-Path (Split-Path (Get-Package Dapper).Source) lib/netstandard*) | 
    Sort-Object { [version] ($_.Name -replace '^netstandard') })[-1] |
      Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dll -Recurse |
        ForEach-Object { Add-Type -LiteralPath $_.FullName }
  ```

  - The above looks for the *highest available* .NET Standard version DLLs; if you want to target a *specific version*, the command becomes easier; e.g., for .NET Standard `2.0`:

    ```bash
      Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.dll -LiteralPath (Join-Path (Split-Path (Get-Package Dapper).Source) lib/netstandard2.0) |
        ForEach-Object { Add-Type -LiteralPath $_.FullName }
    ```

Answer (score 6):

Are you using Powershell 5?  Because if you are, it has a package management module:

[image: PackageManagement Module in Powershell 5]

It appears to be open source: https://github.com/OneGet

Comment: Is there are trick to getting this to work? I get this message: `Find-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'Dapper'. Try Get-PackageSource to see all
available registered package sources.`

Comment: Kind of nutty, but the NuGet location was wrong. I had to unregister the provider `Unregister-PackageSource nuget.org` and then re-register it `Register-PackageSource -Name nuget.org -Location http://www.nuget.org/api/v2 -Force -Trusted`.

Comment: `Set-PackageSource` with the `-Location` flag does absolutely nothing... just awesome.

Comment: @TravisParks: A pain, indeed: I don't know where it comes from, but PSv5.1 installations may end up with a newer, but unsupported API URL (`https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`) that prevents `Find-Package` / `Install-Package` from finding NuGet packages. As for `Set-PackageSource`: you need to use `-NewLocation`.