# How to add an event Action handler in PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, event-handling, terminal.gui

[Terminal.Gui (gui.cs)](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs) provides a `Button` class with a `Clicked` event defined as:

```cs
        public event Action Clicked;
```

I'm trying to write a sample app for Terminal.Gui in PowerShell and am struggling to get an event handler wired up.

```bsh
Add-Type -AssemblyName Terminal.Gui
[Terminal.Gui.Application]::Init() 
$win = New-Object Terminal.Gui.Window
$win.Title = "Hello World"
$btn = New-Object Terminal.Gui.Button
$btn.X = [Terminal.Gui.Pos]::Center()
$btn.Y = [Terminal.Gui.Pos]::Center()
$btn.Text= "Press me"

# Here lies dragons
[Action]$btn.Clicked = {
    [Terminal.Gui.Application]::RequestStop() 
}

$win.Add($btn)

[Terminal.Gui.Application]::Top.Add($win)
[Terminal.Gui.Application]::Run()
```

The `Clicked =` assignment in the sample above returns an error:

`InvalidOperation: The property 'Clicked' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.`

But intellisense auto-completes `Clicked` for me... So I'm guessing it's a type issue?

I can't find any PowerShell docs on `[Action]` and no other samples I've found have given me any joy.

How does one define an event handler for an `Action`-based dotnet event in PowerShell?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Steve Lee's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64180591/45375) provides the crucial pointer; let me complement it with **background information**:

PowerShell offers two fundamental event-subscription mechanism:

- (a) **.NET-native**, as shown in Steve's answer, where you attach a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) as a *delegate* to an object's `<Name>` event via the `.add_<Name>()` instance method (a delegate is a piece of user-supplied callback code to be invoked when the event fires) - see next section.
- (b) **PowerShell-mediated**, using the [`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent) and related cmdlets:

  - A callback-based approach, similar to (a), is available by passing a script block to the `-Action` paramter.
  - Alternatively, queued events can be retrieved on demand via the [`Get-Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-event) cmdlet.

Method (b)'s callback approach only works in a timely fashion while *PowerShell* is in control of the foreground thread, which is *not* the case here, because the `[Terminal.Gui.Application]::Run()` call *blocks* it.
Therefore, method (a) must be used.

---

Re (a):

***C#* offers *syntactic sugar* in the form of operators `+=` and `-=` for attaching and detaching event-handler delegates**, which *look* like *assignments*, but are in reality translated to `add_<Event>()` and `remove_<Event>()` *method calls*.

You can see these method names as follows, using the [`[powerShell]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PowerShell) type as an example:

```
PS> [powershell].GetEvents() | select Name, *Method, EventHandlerType


Name             : InvocationStateChanged
AddMethod        : Void add_InvocationStateChanged(System.EventHandler`1[System.Management.Automation.PSInvocationStateChangedEventArgs])
RemoveMethod     : Void remove_InvocationStateChanged(System.EventHandler`1[System.Management.Automation.PSInvocationStateChangedEventArgs])
RaiseMethod      : 
EventHandlerType : System.EventHandler`1[System.Management.Automation.PSInvocationStateChangedEventArgs]
```

**PowerShell offers *no* such syntactic sugar for attaching/removing event handlers**, so the methods must be called directly.

Unfortunately, neither [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) nor tab-completion are aware of these methods, while, conversely, the raw event *names* confusingly *do* get tab-completed, even though you cannot directly act on them.

[Github suggestion #12926](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12926) aims to address both problems.

**Conventions used for event definitions**:

The `EventHandlerType` property above shows the type name of the event-handler delegate, which in this case properly adheres to the *convention* of using a delegate based on generic type [`System.EventHandler<TEventArgs>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler-1), whose signature is:

```
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object? sender, TEventArgs e);
```

`TEventArgs` represents the type of the instance that contains *event-specific information*.
Another *convention* is that such event-arguments type are derived from the [`System.EventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.EventArgs) class, which the type at hand, [`PSInvocationStateChangedEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSInvocationStateChangedEventArgs), is.

Events that provide *no* event-specific information *by convention* use the non-generic [`System.EventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.EventHandler) delegate:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object? sender, EventArgs e);
```

Presumably, because this delegate was historically used for *all* delegates, even for those *with* event arguments - before *generics* came along in .NET 2 - an `EventArgs` parameter is still present, and the convention is to pass `EventArgs.Empty` rather than `null` to signal the absence of arguments.
Similarly, long-established framework types define non-generic *custom* delegates with their specific event-arguments type, e.g. [`System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keypresseventhandler).

**None of these conventions are *enforced* by the CLR**, however, as evidenced by the event in question being defined as `public event Action Clicked;`, which uses a *parameterless* delegate as the event handler.

**It is generally advisable to adhere to the conventions** so as not contravene user expectations, even though doing so is sometimes less convenient.

---

**PowerShell is very flexible when it comes to using script blocks (`{ ... }`) as delegates, and it notably does *not* enforce a specific *parameter signature*** via `param(...)`:

The script block is accepted irrespective of whether it declares any, too many, or too few parameters, although those arguments that are actually passed by the event-originating object that do bind to script-block parameters must be type-compatible (assuming the script block's parameters are explicitly typed).

Thus, Steve's code:

```
$btn.Add_Clicked({
    param($sender, $e)
    [Terminal.Gui.Application]::RequestStop()
})
```

still worked, despite the useless parameter declarations, given that no arguments are ever passed to the script block, given that the [`System.Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Action) delegate type is *parameterless*.

The following is sufficient:

```
$btn.Add_Clicked({
  [Terminal.Gui.Application]::RequestStop()
})
```

Note: Even without declaring parameters you you can refer to the event sender (the object that triggered the event) via the [automatic `$this` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#this) (in this case, the same as `$btn`).

---

**Streamlined sample code**:

- It is important to call `[Terminal.Gui.Application]::Shutdown()` in order to **return the terminal to a usable state after exiting the application**
- **At least one of the `Terminal.Gui` types isn't PowerShell-friendly**:

  - What are conceptually *text* properties aren't implemented as type `[string]`, but as `[NStack.ustring]`; while you can use `[string]` instances transparently to *assign* to such properties, *displaying* them again performs enumeration and renders the *code points* of the underlying characters *individually*.

    - Workaround: call `.ToString()`; e.g. `$btn.Text.ToString()`
- **As of PowerShell 7.3.2, there is no direct integration with NuGet packages**, so it is quite cumbersome to load an installed package's assemblies into a PowerShell session - see **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50004706/45375)**, which **shows how to use the *.NET Core SDK* to download a package and also make its dependencies available**.

  - In *PowerShell (Core) 7.2+*, the problem can be worked around *in this case*: The [`Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleGuiTools` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleGuiTools) *ships with* `Terminal.Gui.dll`, so you can install that module, and reference the DLL there.

    - This workaround is is courtesy of Jonathan DeMarks from [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/gui-cs/Terminal.Gui/issues/945#issuecomment-1420955249), and it is integrated into the sample code below.
    - In *Windows PowerShell* you'll have to follow the steps in the [aforementioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50004706/45375) first to make `Terminal.Gui.dll` available in order for the sample code to run.
  - Note that `Add-Type -AssemblyName` only works with assemblies that are either in the *current* directory (as opposed to the *script's* directory) or ship with PowerShell itself (PowerShell [Core] v6+) / are in the GAC (Windows PowerShell).
  - Given how cumbersome use of NuGet packages from PowerShell currently is, [GitHub feature suggestion #6724](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6724) asks for `Add-Type` to be enhanced to support NuGet packages directly.

```
using namespace Terminal.Gui

# Load the Terminal.Gui.dll assembly, if necessary.
if (-not ('Terminal.Gui.Application' -as [Type])) {
  if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -ge '7.2') {
    # Load the Terminal.Gui assembly via the 'Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleGuiTools'
    # module, by installing that module on demand.
    if (-not (Get-Module -ListAvailable Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleGuiTools)) {
      Write-Verbose -Verbose "Installing module Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleGuiTools on demand, in the current user's scope."
      Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser -ErrorAction Stop Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleGuiTools
    }
    # Terminal.Gui.dll is inside the module's folder.
    try { Add-Type -LiteralPath (Join-Path (Get-Module -ListAvailable Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleGuiTools).ModuleBase Terminal.Gui.dll) } catch { throw }
  }
  else {
    # Windows PowerShell (or earlier PS Core versions)
    # Unfortunately, there's no easy way to gain access to Terminal.Gui.dll, and the
    # best option is to use an aux. NET SDK project as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50004706/45375
    # The next command assumes that the steps there have been followed.
    try { Add-Type -Path $HOME\.nuget-pwsh\packages-winps\terminal.gui\*\Terminal.Gui.dll } catch { throw }
  }
}

# Initialize the "GUI".
# Note: This must come before creating windows and controls.
[Application]::Init()

$win = [Window] @{
  Title = 'Hello World'
}

$btn = [Button] @{
  X    = [Pos]::Center()
  Y    = [Pos]::Center()
  Text = 'Quit'
}
$win.Add($btn)
[Application]::Top.Add($win)

# Attach an event handler to the button.
# Note: Register-ObjectEvent -Action is NOT an option, because
# the [Application]::Run() method that isused to display the window is blocking.
$btn.add_Clicked({
    # Close the modal window.
    # This call is also necessary to stop printing garbage in response to mouse
    # movements later.
    [Application]::RequestStop()
  })

# Show the window (takes over the whole screen). 
# Note: This is a blocking call.
[Application]::Run()

# Required to restore the previous terminal screen
# and for being able to rerun the application in the same session.
[Application]::Shutdown()
```

Comment: I'm learning about events and happen to notice that you mention "you can refer to the event sender ... via the automatic $this variable".  For completion, you might add that $e can be referred to via automatic $_ variable.  I don't fully understand when and where this works, but seems true when an instance of a class inheriting from EventArgs is passed as an argument.  I have code where it worked with MouseDown, MouseMove, and Paint events in WinForms.  And Yesterday I created a C# class from scratch and $_ was available in the PowerShell script using it.

Comment: @Darin, even if that works (I've never tried), I wouldn't rely on it, given that it is neither documented nor makes sense conceptually.

Comment: Looks like the closest to docs I can find is [WPF & PowerShell — Part 3 (Handling Events)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/wpf-powershell-part-3-handling-events/) by James Brundage: "It is possible to cast a script block to an event handler. The script block has two variables: $this (which is the sender), and $_, which contains the event arguments."

Comment: @Darin, if you can get it to work _consistently_, you could try to convince the documentation team to document it as such. However, as stated, conceptually it doesn't make sense to me, and [even the way `$this` currently works is problematic](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/8207#issuecomment-940127593).

Comment: Thank you for the link.  Kind of sad they didn't make it `$sender` and `$e` from day one.  All the programmer would have to remember is placing the $ in front of the parameter names they normally use in C#.  Based on the issue with `$this`, and what I'm now running into with `Register-EngineEvent` and `New-Event`, I'm thinking I will standardize my code with `$sender` and `$e`, either via `param()` or direct assignment as needed.  Thank you for taking the time to respond to my comments and have a good evening/day.

Answer (score 9):

The C# code would be adding a lambda:

```cs
btn.Clicked += ...
```

So in PowerShell, you need to explicitly call the Add_Clicked() method:

```
$btn.Add_Clicked({
    [Terminal.Gui.Application]::RequestStop()
})
```

The params match the method signature although not used in this example.

Comment: Nice, though note that the standard signature you're showing  (more specifically, `param([object] $sender, [EventArgs] $eventArgs)`, where a class _derived from_ `[EventArgs]` is by convention used to pass actual arguments) happens not to apply here, because the event in question is defined in a nonstandard way: it is declared as taking an [`Action`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Action) delegate, which is _parameterless_. Terminology quibble: event handlers are _delegates_, and in C# both regular methods and lambda expressions (anonymous methods) can serve as such.

Answer (score 2):

This change does not display the error but the event seems *not* to be firing.

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $btn -EventName Clicked --Action {
        [Terminal.Gui.Application]::RequestStop() 
}
```

**Edit:**

@Steve Lee's solution works like a charm, but what is also needed is to add `[Terminal.Gui.Application]::Shutdown()` at the end. The `param($sender,$e)` is not needed because it's not a `EventHandler` but a `event Action`. Thanks.