# Why is the Typedefinition null?

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to run some c# code through powershell (just for fun). I am including a short sample of the code because the actual program itself is too long and is not really the focus of this question here.

```
#Referencing assemblies #"referencedAssemblies", "Using" keyword equivalent in C#
$assemblies = ("System.Core", "System.Net.Http", "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq", "System.Xml.Linq","System.Data","System.Xml", "System.Data.DataSetExtensions", "Microsoft.CSharp")
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $assemblies -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp

$id = get-random #Workaround to allow code changes without having to load type into the same App Domain again, especially since unfortunately, you cannot unload type. 
$code = @"
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace Test
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Call the REST API method.
            Console.WriteLine("\nExtracting text...\n");
            ReadText(PDFFilePath).Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress Enter to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
"@
 
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp 
iex "[Test.Program$id]::Main()"
```

I already installed Nuget and the HTTP and Newtonsoft required packages:

```
Install-PackageProvider Nuget –force –verbose
nstall-Module PackageManagement -Force -Repository PSGallery
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -SkipDependencies -verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -SkipDependencies -verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

When i run the ps1 file, i am getting the following errors:

```
Add-Type : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'TypeDefinition' because it is null.    
Add-Type : c:\..The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Add-Type : c:\..The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the
namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

why is that? i am clearly referencing the assemblies and loading them here:

```
$assemblies = ("System.Core", "System.Net.Http", "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq", "System.Xml.Linq","System.Data","System.Xml", "System.Data.DataSetExtensions", "Microsoft.CSharp")
```

Comment: Read the error message: `$code` is `null` because you're using it before it's assigned. The remaining error messages happen on the second `Add-Type` call, which is lacking the assemblies. Even if all this is fixed I'm fairly sure you won't get things to compile because `Add-Type` has no support for referencing packages. `Newtonsoft.Json` will not be on the path or in the GAC after `Install-Package`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert oh you're right...so i placed the `Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $assemblies -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp` at the end and most of the errors got resolved. now i am getting `Add-Type : (0) : Metadata file 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.dll' could not be found`. Isnt there any way around this or to allow support?

Comment: Not easily. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257572/loading-assemblies-from-nuget-packages) seems to be a fairly extensive overview of the matter.