# SQLKata with SQLite minimal example (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, sqlite, sqlkata

I have a sqlite database say c:\myDb.sqlite

I have figured out how to build a query to this db in SQLKata:

```
$query = New-Object SqlKata.Query("myTable")
$compiler = New-Object SqlKata.Compilers.SqliteCompiler
$query.Where("myColumn", "1")
$result = $compiler.Compile($query)
```

But I have no clue at all how to submit this to my Sqlite database.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting this to work *from PowerShell* is hampered by two difficulties:

- Loading the assemblies related to NuGet packages in general and the [`Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite) NuGet package in particular often requires extra, non-obvious work in PowerShell.
- PowerShell generally doesn't surface *extension methods* as such - e.g. `.Get()` on query instances - necessitating explicit calls to the static methods of [`[SqlKata.Execution.QueryExtensions]`](https://github.com/sqlkata/querybuilder/blob/master/SqlKata.Execution/Query.Extensions.cs) instead.

Specifically, using NuGet packages from PowerShell requires the following steps, which are neither convenient nor obvious:

- Merely installing NuGet packages with [`Install-Package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/packagemanagement/install-package) or trying to use them from the local cache created by .NET SDK projects in `$HOME/.nuget/packages` is often *not* enough, because any assemblies *they depend on* aren't then present in the same directory, which is what [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) requires.
- They must also be unpacked in a platform-appropriate manner via an auxiliary .NET SDK project to a single target folder (per package or combined), as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50004706/45375).
- *Additionally*, for the `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` package, the platform-appropriate *native* library (e.g., `win-x64\native\*.dll` from the "runtimes" folder subtree of the .NET SDK project's publish folder) must be copied *directly* to the target folder in PowerShell (Core), but curiously not in Windows PowerShell, at least as of package version 5.0.9

---

The following **sample code uses the `Add-NuGetType` helper function**, available from [this MIT-licensed Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/7436c9e4b2f73d7256498f959f0d5a7c), which automates all of the steps above:

Note:

- Assuming you have looked at the linked code to ensure that it is safe (which I can personally assure you of, but you should always check), you can install `Add-NuGetType` directly as follows (instructions for how to make the function available in future sessions or to convert it to a script will be displayed):

  ```sh
  irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/7436c9e4b2f73d7256498f959f0d5a7c/raw/Add-NuGetType.ps1 | iex
  ```
- When first run, the function downloads and installs a private copy of the .NET SDK embedded inside the folder in which NuGet packages downloaded later are cached. This initial installation takes a while, and the `-Verbose` switch used below reports its progress.
- `Add-NuGetType` is *not* meant for *production use*, but for *experimentation* with NuGet packages; run `help Add-NuGetType` for more information.

```sh
# Reference the relevant namespaces.
using namespace SqlKata
using namespace SqlKata.Compilers
using namespace SqlKata.Execution
using namespace Microsoft.Data.Sqlite

# Load the SqlKata and Sqlite asssemblies.
# See the comments above for how to install the Add-NuGetType function.
# Note: On first call, a private copy of the .NET SDK is downloaded
#       on demand, which takes a while.
Add-NuGetType -Verbose SqlKata, SqlKata.Execution, Microsoft.Data.Sqlite

# First, create sample database './sample.db' with table 'sample_table'
@'
create table sample_table (Name string, Age int); 
insert into sample_table (Name, Age) values ("JDoe", 42), ("JRoe", 43);
.save ./sample.db
'@ | sqlite3

# Create a [SqliteConnection] instance...
$connection = [SqliteConnection]::new("Data Source=$PWD/sample.db")
# ... and create a query factory for it.
$sqliteDb = [QueryFactory]::new($connection, [SqlServerCompiler]::new())

# Create and execute a sample query.
$query = $sqliteDb.Query("sample_table").Where("Name", "JRoe")
# Note the need to use the static methods of [SqlKata.Execution.QueryExtensions],
# because PowerShell doesn't make *extension methods* automatically available.
[SqlKata.Execution.QueryExtensions]::Get($query) # outputs [Dapper.SqlMapper+DapperRow] instances
```