# Howto install a PowerShell binary cmdlet (C#) from a NuGet package with its dependencies

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I've developed a binary cmdlet using C#. The project's TargetFramework is *netstandard2.0* and the assembly (the dll) is published as a NuGet package. This assembly and thus the NuGet package has a few dependencies (i.e. other NuGets).

What is the best way to install my binary cmdlet locally on a computer using PowerShell, so my cmdlet becomes available on that computer to be called from PowerShell scripts. I.e., can I install the NuGet with a Powershell command such that my DLL and its dependencies become available to PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of PowerShell 7.2, there is *no* support for direct installation of NuGet packages.

- [GitHub issue #6724](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6724) asks for such support.

Your options are:

- If feasible, *repackage* your binary cmdlet and its dependencies as a PowerShell [module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules), which can then be installed via [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module):

  - A PowerShell module is typically a *directory* named for the module, which contains a [module manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-modulemanifest) file (`*.psd1`) with metadata about the module alongside the files that make up the implementation of the module; in the case of a module wrapping a cmdlet DLL, the manifest's `RootModule` entry references that DLL, and the `RequiredAssemblies` entry references the dependencies.
  - When [`Publish-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PowershellGet/Publish-Module) is called to publish a module, it is packaged as a NuGet package *with a custom structure* that `Import-Module` understands; typically, PowerShell modules are published to the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/).
  - Perhaps this is a viable starting point: [Creating a new module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/writing-portable-modules#creating-a-new-module)
- Otherwise, use an aux. .NET SDK project to install your NuGet package, which is a nontrivial process outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50004706/45375).

  - [This MIT-licensed Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/7436c9e4b2f73d7256498f959f0d5a7c) contains helper function `Add-NuGetType`, which automates the process and additionally supports *native* library dependencies in PowerShell (Core) 7+, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69126680/45375); however, note that the latter doesn't offer strict version control, and therefore shouldn't be used in production.