# Is there a module for parsing TOML files in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, toml

I'm trying to find a [TOML](https://toml.io) file parser for PowerShell.

I can't find any information about it either in [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/) or in the preinstalled PowerShell functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, **as of this writing, there seems to be no *PowerShell* module for [TOML](https://toml.io/) parsing** published in the *PowerShell Gallery*:

- [Searching for "TOML"](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages?q=toml) yields no relevant matches as of this writing.

However, **there is a *.NET* package available** in the *NuGet Gallery*:

- **[Tomlyn](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tomlyn/)**, whose source-code repository is [here](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml).

---

While **you *can* consume NuGet packages from PowerShell, doing so is nontrivial as of PowerShell Core 7.2.2**, unfortunately.

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50004706/45375) discusses the current pitfalls and potential future enhancements.
- In *this particular case, because the package has no dependencies*, you can get away with downloading the package via [`Install-Package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/packagemanagement/install-package), as shown below:

**Sample use**:

```sh
# Determine the package's local installation location.
# If it isn't installed, install it first, in the current user's scope.
while (-not ($installDir = (Get-Package -ErrorAction Ignore -ProviderName NuGet Tomlyn).Source)) {
  $null = Install-Package -Scope CurrentUser -ErrorAction Stop -ProviderName NuGet Tomlyn
}

# Load the package's assembly into the session.
Add-Type -ErrorAction Stop -LiteralPath (Join-Path $installDir '../lib/netstandard2.0/Tomlyn.dll')

# Define a sample TOML string to parse.
$tomlStr = @'
global = "this is a string"
# This is a comment of a table
[my_table]
key = 1 # Comment a key
value = true
list = [4, 5, 6]
'@

# Parse the TOML string into an object mod)el (nested dictionaries).
$tomlTable = [Tomlyn.Toml]::ToModel($tomlStr)

# Output the '[my_table]' section's 'list' value.
#  -> 4, 5, 6
# IMPORTANT: Use ['<key>'] syntax; .<key> syntax does NOT work.
$tomlTable['my_table']['list']
```

Note:

- With with dictionary types, PowerShell *usually* allows interchangeable use of index syntax (e.g. `['my_table']`) and dot notation , via `.`, the member-access operator (e.g. `.my_table`).
- However, dot notation is *not* supported for the dictionaries of type `[Tomlyn.Model.Table]`, such as returned by `[Tomlyn.Toml]::ToModel()`, presumably because that type only implements the *generic* `` IDictionary`2 `` interface, and not also its non-generic counterpart, `IDictionary`.

  - See [GitHub issue #17190](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17190) for a discussion.