# How to read a TRUE or FALSE from a .conf file with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, configuration-files

I am trying to build a small program that shutdown WSL and other programs that are running WSL in it like Windows Terminal.

I want the user to be able to set TRUE or FALSE in a .conf file variable depending on if the Windows Terminal wants to be closed or not by checking it with a conditional but when i add the if statement checking for the variable the program just simply doesn't work.Any ideas on where i could be making the mistake?

Here is the code:

```
# Gets the settings from the conig file
Foreach ($i in $(Get-Content stop.conf))
{
    Set-Variable -Name $i.split("=")[0] -Value $i.split("=",2)[1]
}

# Cheks for open processes and saves it to a variable
$IDE = Get-Process $EDITOR -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$windowsTerminal = Get-Process $windowsterminal -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$linuxsys = Get-Process $DISTRO -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# OPTIONAL
# Checks if Windows Terminal is open and closes it
if ($WINTERMINAL -eq $true)
{
    if ($windowsTerminal)
    {
        # Try gratefully first
        $windowsTerminal.CloseMainWindow()
        Sleep 5
        if (!$windowsTerminal.HasExited)
        {
            $windowsTerminal | Stop-Process -Force
        }
    }
}
```

Just in case the .conf file looks like this:

```
DISTRO=ubuntu2004
EDITOR=code
WINTERMINAL=$true
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `conf.json` file then you wouldn't have a need to manually parse your file?

Comment: You can use `if([bool]::Parse($WINTERMINAL.TrimStart('$'))) { .... # condition for true here }` tho I'm against it :)

Comment: I am starting to think that the good option is going to be to go for the json file as nothing seems to work, thank you for your help tho! Is helping me a lot to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @santiago-squarzon that a .JSON file would be easier here.  Part of the reason it would be easier here would be that you would automatically get support for certain data types, like Boolean.

However, I think your code could work with a couple of minors changes:

```
# Gets the settings from the conig file
Foreach ($i in $(Get-Content stop.conf))
{
    # Change one, using $executionContext here (speed)
    $varName, $varValue = $i.Split("=", 2)
    $executionContext.SessionState.PSVariable.Set($varName, $varValue)
}

# Cheks for open processes and saves it to a variable
$IDE = Get-Process $EDITOR -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$windowsTerminal = Get-Process $windowsterminal -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$linuxsys = Get-Process $DISTRO -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# At this point, your variables are all strings.  There's two ways forward from here:
# 1. Make it an actual boolean
# 2. Match potential yes values (I'll do #2)
if ($WINTERMINAL -match "^(?>$true|yes|y)$")
{
    if ($windowsTerminal)
    {
        # Try gratefully first
        $windowsTerminal.CloseMainWindow()
        Sleep 5
        if (!$windowsTerminal.HasExited)
        {
            $windowsTerminal | Stop-Process -Force
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I'm choosing to match instead of `[bool]::Parse($winTerminal)` is that your original code had a truth value of "Yes", not "True".  If you want to provide a more human-friendly option than "true" or "false", this is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort to help, but sadly idk why it does not seem to work, i will try to implement this with a json config file, hope i have more luck!

Comment: What is your expected value for true?

Comment: I was expecting that `$WINTERMINAL` to return true but i think i finally solved the problem. Thanks to the help i was able to figure out what i was doing wrong which was several things.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're reading from a plain-text file, your dynamically created variables based on the file's content will contain *string* values.

Thus, use a [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) to check for a string with *verbatim value* `$true` (as opposed to the [automatic (built-in) `$true` *variable*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#true) (conceptually, a constant), which is a *Boolean*)<sup>[1]</sup>:

```bash
if ($WINTERMINAL -eq '$true') # Note the '...' quoting; ditto for '$false'
```

If you want to be more flexible and also accept verbatim `true` and `yes` (or any case variation thereof - note that PowerShell is generally case-*insensitive* by default):

```bash
if ($WINTERMINAL -in '$true', 'true', 'yes')
```

---

Note:

- While using **JSON** as your config file's format, as suggested, would indeed give you support for a few *data types* (other than string), including Booleans, **maintaining JSON files *manually* is error-prone**.
- A **friendlier format that is also type-aware**, which PowerShell does *not* natively support, however, is **[TOML](https://toml.io/en/)**, which you can think of as a typed superset of INI files (`.ini`)

  - [GitHub issue #9035](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9035#issuecomment-469417212), which was *declined*, asked for INI-file support, in the context of which TOML support was discussed too.
  - As of this writing, there are [*no* TOML modules in the PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages?q=toml).

    - You can use a .NET library such as [`Tomlyn`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tomlyn/) directly, but use of NuGet packages in PowerShell is currently cumbersome, unfortunately - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71993788/45375) for an example.

---

<sup>[1] When you coerce a Boolean to a string, such as in an `-eq` operation with a string as the LHS, `$true` and `$false` become verbatim strings `True` and `False`, respectively. E.g., `'True' -eq $true` is true.</sup>

Comment: I have tryed but it does not seem to work, i don't know why, but thank you so much for the help and for all the interesting information i did not know about! : )

Comment: Glad to hear the information was helpful, @ZumoDeZumos. However, _in what way_ did the solution in this answer not work? With your sample file content and the code for reading it from your question, it does work for me.

Comment: Tbh i don't fully know how to respond to your question as this is actually my first time making and learning how to make a powershell script and i am not quite sure of all the mistakes i was able to solve. The thing is that the main problem was several Syntax Errors.