# pwsh 7 format-default: Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime' to type 'System.IFormattable'

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, powershell-7.2

I need to read data from mysql database with pwsh 7.
On powershell 5 it is working fine but with pwsh 7 not with , and receive an error message when querying a table with 'timestamp' data :

"format-default: Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime' to type 'System.IFormattable'."

```
 [void][system.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
        $connStr = "server=" + $MySQLHost + ";port=" + $MySQLPort + ";uid=" + $user + ";pwd=" + $pass + ";database=" + $MYSQLDatabase + ";Pooling=FALSE;Allow Zero Datetime=true;Allow User Variables=True;Connect Timeout=60"
        $conn = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection($connStr)
        $conn.Open()
        New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("USE $database", $conn)
        
    $query = "select Name, InputDate from ENVIRONMENT"
    $cmd = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($query, $conn)    
    $dataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($cmd)
    $dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "data")
    $cmd.Dispose() 
    
    $dataSet.Tables["data"]
```

So I can see that after "$dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "data")" data are collected from mysql because it return the number of row. But after "$dataSet.Tables["data"]" it return the error.

In powershell 5 it is working fine.

Any help :-) ?

Thanks

Comment: It is the same, pwsh cannot cast the object DatTime

ConvertTo-Json: Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime' to type 'System.IFormattable'.

Comment: I thing I understood what you explain. I did that but it convert everything into string unfortunatelly, I don't know how to do better

 $members = $($dataSet.Tables["data"] | Get-Member -MemberType Property).Name
        $d = @()
        foreach($data in $dataSet.Tables["data"]){
            $psObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
                foreach($memberName in $members ){
                    $psObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $memberName -Value $data.$memberName.tostring()
                }
            $d += $psObj
        }

        return $d

Comment: I have measure the time it takes to do what I proposed in my previous comment, and it is very slow compare to the regular 'return $dataSet.Tables["data"] '. Do you know another way to do such dataset that can convert MysqlDateTime ? I'm a bit confuse because in pwsh 5 it can convert, but not with pwsh 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code works in Windows PowerShell, but not in PowerShell (Core) 7+, I encourage you to report an issue in the [PowerShell GitHub repo](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues).

However, you should first make sure that you're loading the .NET (Core)-appropriate version of the assembly (`MySql.Data`) from the [`MySql.Data` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data), given that `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")` may be loading an older, .NET Framework-only version from the GAC (Global Assembly Cache), as would the equivalent - and preferable - form `Add-Type -AssemblyName MySql.Data`.

Unfortunately, using NuGet packages isn't well supported in PowerShell as of version 7.2.x:

- [GitHub issue #6724](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6724) asks for better support in the future.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50004706/45375) shows how to make it work currently - which is far from trivial.

---

Some thoughts about the error and a potential - slow - workaround:

[`MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_Types_MySqlDateTime.htm) indeed does *not* implement the [`System.IFormattable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IFormattable) interface. It's unclear to me why this cast is even attempted or - in case the attempt is by design - why the exception isn't caught.

When PowerShell stringifies objects, it checks for whether they implement the `IFormattable`, so that a culture-*invariant* string representation can be requested. Conceivably, the bug has to do with mistakenly believing `MySqlDateTime` to implement this interface.

`MySqlDateTime` does have an [explicit conversion operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_Types_MySqlDateTime_op_Explicit.htm) to .NET's `[datetime]` ([`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)) type, which you should be able to use from PowerShell with a `[datetime]` *cast*.

Thus, the following approach *may* work as a workaround:

- For a given table's rows, replace the `MySqlDateTime`-typed properties (columns) with properties that explicitly convert the values to `[datetime]`, with the help of [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) and [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties).
- Note that such an approach will be *slow*, because a new object must be constructed for each row, which also means that the type identity of the rows will be lost.

Note: The following is a simplified, self-contained example that simulates your MySQL data types; for simplicity, type `[string]` is used in lieu of
`[MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime]` to modify the columns of interest with an explicit `[datetime]` cast - adapt accordingly.

```
# These sample rows simulate the following:
#   $rows = $dataSet.Tables["data"]
$rows = @(
  [pscustomobject] @{ 
    foo = 1; 
    bar = '1970/01/01'
  },
  [pscustomobject] @{ 
    foo = 2; 
    bar = '1970/01/02'
  }
)

# Get the first row, so the data types of its properties (columns)
# can be analyzed.
# (I assume there's a way to do this directly via a table object,
#  and its column definitions, but I'm not familiar with the MySQL .NET API.)
$firstRow = $rows | Select-Object -First 1

# Construct an array of property names / calculated properties to pass
# to Select-Object below.
$propArray = foreach ($prop in $firstRow.psobject.Properties) {
  if ($prop.Value -is [string]) { # Substitute [MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime] here.
    @{
      Name = $prop.Name
      Expression = [scriptblock]::Create("[datetime] `$_.$($prop.Name)")
    }
  }
  else {
    $prop.Name
  }
}

# Now output all rows with the [MySqlDateTime] columns (properties)
# converted to [datetime].
$rows | Select-Object $propArray
```

Comment: Many thanks ! the code is perfect, good idea to recreate new "select-object" conversion

Comment: Agreed. Although it would be nice if this workaround wasn't needed, I got tired of fighting with this issue and just added your code to a PS module I wrote a long time ago for interacting with MySql. Works great for my purposes and I'm up and running again. Thanks

Comment: I left the comment above, although I wound up finding a little flaw. If one of the DateTime objects in the first row is null, the -is fails to catch it because the type is System.DbNull. If anyone else is interested, a simple hack workaround is just to change the final line of your code to "$rows | Select-Object $propArray | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json"

Comment: Thanks, @user2233949, but wouldn't this workaround imply that `$rows | Select-Object * | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json` _alone_ would work for you too? However, given the limited number of data types supported in JSON, this is probably not a _generally robust_ workaround. Do you know of a way to examine the column data types without having to look at specific rows?

Comment: It does work in the sense that it doesn't produce an exception, but it also produces slightly different results. So I guess each person would have to weigh which is better. If you don't use the [scriptblock] method in the answer and just Convert*-JSON then the date time properties will be of type System.DateTime, but if you use the answer, the type is PsCustomObject. It's definitely not an ideal solution either way. It works for my purposes though, which is non-production, so I just went with it.

Comment: @user2233949, this answer still produces `[datetime]` (`System.DateType`) instances, it's just that they're - _mostly_ invisibly - wrapped in `[psobject]` (confusingly aka `[pscustomobject]`) instances due to using a script block as the value of the calculated property, but `-is [datetime]` still reports `$true` for them;  see [GitHub issue #5579](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579)