# How to click save button of Paint using UIAutomation?

Tags: powershell, winapi, ui-automation

I'm trying to click on paint's save button, but it's not recognizing the window controls. Am I doing something wrong? For example this code only recognizes the title of the window, but does not recognize the controls of that window.

Can anyone help?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName UIAutomationClient
Add-Type -AssemblyName UIAutomationTypes
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Xml.Linq

$nameProcess = "mspaint"
$windowTitle = "Untitled"


$processes = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcessesByName($nameProcess)

foreach ($process in $processes) {
    if ($process.MainWindowTitle.Contains($windowTitle)) {
        if ($process -ne $null) {
            $root = [System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement]::FromHandle($process.MainWindowHandle)
            $elements = $root.FindAll([System.Windows.Automation.TreeScope]::Subtree, [System.Windows.Automation.Condition]::TrueCondition) | Select-Object -Unique
            
            foreach ($item in $elements) {           
                if ($item -ne $null) {                 
                    $pattern = $null
                    if ($item.TryGetCurrentPattern([System.Windows.Automation.InvokePattern]::Pattern, [ref]$pattern)) {
                        write-host $item.Current.Name -ForegroundColor Green
                        if ($item.Current.Name -eq "Save") {
                            $pattern.Invoke()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Select-Object -Unique` doesn't work here. If I remove that, it still only lists the window control buttons like "Minimize" and "Maximize". The cause could be that  `System.Windows.Automation` uses UIA2 interfaces only, which either don't work or are not reliable when working with some newer applications. The newer UIA3 interfaces unfortunately don't have a .NET counterpart, which make them harder to use. There are 3rd party libraries like FlaUI that provide UIA3 wrappers. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73541499/7571258) for a way to use FlaUI in PowerShell.

Comment: I'm able to locate the "save" button using [Accessibility Insights for Windows](https://github.com/microsoft/accessibility-insights-windows), which seems to suggest that automation is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have commented, MSPaint of Windows 10 and newer versions propably doesn't support the old UIA2 interfaces and requires UIA3 instead.

I've been able to press the "save" button using the [FlaUI](https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI) library (a .NET wrapper for UIA2 and UIA3), after following the steps from the first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73541499/7571258) to download its binaries from NuGet.

```sh
Add-Type -Path $PSScriptRoot\assemblies\bin\Release\net48\publish\FlaUI.UIA3.dll

# Create UIA3 interface
$automation = [FlaUI.UIA3.UIA3Automation]::new()

# For each mspaint process
foreach( $process in Get-Process mspaint ) {

    # Attach FlaUI to the process
    $app = [FlaUI.Core.Application]::Attach( $process )

    # For each top level window of mspaint
    foreach( $wnd in $app.GetAllTopLevelWindows( $automation ) ) {

        # Filter all descendants - get button named 'Save'
        $wnd.FindAllDescendants() | 
            Where-Object { $_.ControlType -eq 'Button' -and $_.Name -eq 'Save' } | 
            ForEach-Object { 
                # Click the button using the "Invoke" pattern
                $_.Patterns.Invoke.Pattern.Invoke() 
            }  
    }   
}
```

Comment: i needed to run powershell as administrator