# Automating desktop application that is built using delphi FMX

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, desktop

How to automate an Delphi FMX based application?
Earlier application was developed in delphi VCL component  , I automated it using Test Complete
But now I am looking for automating delphi application that uses FMX component

I have tried with different automation tools to identify the properties of the different UI component of the application
But as it is built with FMX components , it is not getting read

Comment: UI controls that are build according to Windows standards, can be automated through Microsoft's UI Automation API. There are basically two usable versions of this, UIA2 (.NET based) and UIA3 (native COM API). Newer applications generally work better with UIA3, while older applications might require UIA2. Do you have a specific requirement for the language in which you want to write the automation code? I've successfully automated a few apps using PowerShell and FlaUI (UIA3). https://stackoverflow.com/a/73541499/7571258