# How to get the title bar of a given window via UI Automation?

Tags: powershell, ui-automation

I am not able to get any "title bar" object of a window via UI automation client. Here the Powershell demo code I am using, but the result is always empty. Even if I list all child-elements of a CMD-window it shows all other elements, but not the title bar. What is wrong here?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'UIAutomationClient'
$cTrue = [Windows.Automation.PropertyCondition]::TrueCondition
$root = [Windows.Automation.AutomationElement]::RootElement
$cmd  = $root.FindAll("Children", $cTrue).where{$_.current.name -eq 'Command Prompt'}

$bar  = [System.Windows.Automation.ControlType]::TitleBar
$prop = [System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement]::ControlTypeProperty
$cond = [System.Windows.Automation.PropertyCondition]::new($prop, $bar)
$cmd.FindFirst("Children", $cond)
```

Comment: Works for me provided I change the `.where` to a `| Where-Object { ... }` I tested using notepad but I doubt that changes anything

Comment: Are you getting some details of that object or just no error? I tested that code in latest Win11 and I dont get the title bar  object back. Even if I try $cTrue as an unfiltered condition in last line.

Comment: I can list the titlebar properties. `> $tb.current.Name
Untitled - Notepad`

Comment: The .NET UIAutomationClient API uses outdated UIA version 2, which is known to have issues with newer applications. I get best results using UIA version 3, which is a native API, so you need a wrapper library to use in .NET languages like PowerShell. See [example using FlaUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73541499/7571258).

Comment: @patthoyts That is the name of the window, but not the titlebar-object (even if it is the same content in this sample).