# powershell locate and load package .dll

Tags: powershell, nuget, package-management

using PowerShell and the iCal.Net package, I want to read an .ics file.

```
# install ical.net dependencies
Install-Package NodaTime -Force

# install ical.net package
Install-Package iCal.Net -Force

# variables
$icsfile = "C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\ical\caalendar.ical"
$icsurl = "https://url_to_download/basic.ics"

# download ics file
Invoke-WebRequest $icsurl -OutFile $icsfile

# create new calendar object
$calendar = New-Object Ical.Net.Calendar
```

While creating the new calendar object I get a message saying

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [Ical.Net.Calendar]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:13
+ $calendar = New-Object Ical.Net.Calendar
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

My guess is that even though the ical.net package is installed, it also has to be loaded. While researching on how to do this, I found that I need to provide the path to a specific .dll file.

How can I find out where this .ddl is located, and how can I load it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed:

- While **[`Install-Package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/packagemanagement/install-package) lets you *install* general-purpose NuGet packages** (containing .NET assemblies for use with any .NET language), there is **no direct PowerShell integration for their *use***, as of version v1.4.8.1 of the `PackageManagement` module.

  - [GitHub issue #6724](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6724) suggests making the use of NuGet packages in PowerShell easier by extending `Add-Type`
  - Note: If `Install-Package` fails to find a NuGet package you know to exist, you may have to upgrade PowerShell's package-management modules first, from an *elevated* session (you don't need elevation if you install only for the *current* user, with `-Scope CurrentUser`):

    ```bash
    Install-Module -Scope AllUsers PowerShellGet -Force
    ```
- You must inded:

  - **locate the appropriate `.dll` file** inside the package
  - and **load it via [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) `-LiteralPath`**, as shown below.
- The **caveat** is:

  - Manually loading an assembly from a NuGet package installed with `Install-Package` ***does* not (always) also automatically load *its dependencies***.
    However, it *does* appear to work with `ICal.Net`.
  - If the method below doesn't work for a given package, you'll need to install it with a **more cumbersome approach that involves an *auxiliary .NET SDK project***, as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50004706/45375).

---

**Manually loading the relevant assembly from the [`Ical.Net`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ical.Net) NuGet package**:

- Inspecting the package via the online [NuGet Package Explorer](https://nuget.info/packages/Ical.Net) reveals that there's a .NET Standard 2.0 `Ical.Net.dll` assembly in subdirectory `lib\netstandard2.0`. .NET Standard 2.0 assemblies are compatible with both *Windows PowerShell* and [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md).
- You can infer the local installation directory of a package installed with `Install-Package` from the `.Source` property of the package-information objects returned by [`Get-Package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/packagemanagement/get-package)

Therefore:

```bash
Add-Type -LiteralPath (Join-Path (Split-Path -Parent (Get-Package ICal.Net).Source) lib\netstandard2.0\Ical.Net.dll)
```