# PowerShell script to check and Skip rows that have yellow cells, gray cells or blank cells

Tags: excel, powershell, epplus

I need to prepare s Powershell script to check my NSG rules design sheet and Skip rows that have yellow cells, gray cells or blank cells. I have prepared below script but it is not working as expected. Can someone please help me to fix this script.

Powershell script:

```
# Load the EPPlus library
Add-Type -Path "/home/lokesh/EPPlus.dll"  # Replace with the path to your EPPlus.dll file

# Create an Excel package object
$excelPackage = New-Object OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage

# Load the Excel file
$filePath = "/home/lokesh/NSG_Rules.xlsx"
$excelPackage = [OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage]::Load($filePath)

# Get the first worksheet from the Excel package
$worksheet = $excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[0]  # Change the index if needed

# Define a function to check cell color
function IsYellow($cell) {
    return ($cell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb -eq "FFFFFF00")  # Yellow color code
}

# Skip rows with yellow, gray, or blank cells
$rowsToKeep = @()
foreach ($row in $worksheet.Cells.Rows) {
    $skipRow = $false
    foreach ($cell in $row.Cells) {
        if (IsYellow($cell) -or $cell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb -eq "FFA9A9A9" -or -not $cell.Value) {
            $skipRow = $true
            break
        }
    }
    if (-not $skipRow) {
        $rowsToKeep += $row
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you in control of your "*NSG rules design sheet*"? If yes I'd recommend to use actual cell content to represent a given state or value insterad of a formatting of a cell. And I'd recomment using the great module from Doug Finke [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel). That would make your life way easier and you could even run your scripts on computers without an installed Excel. ... just my 2 ct. ... ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

- The solution below:

  - **addresses your question *as asked*, based on use of the current version (v7) of the [EPPlus](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus) .NET library *alone***.

    - Note that EPPlus versions v5 and above require a paid license for commercial use.
    - Direct use of this library is not very PowerShell-friendly; the [`ImportExcel`](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) PowerShell module - which actually *builds on* EPPlus - albeit on a locked-in v4.x version due to the v5+ license requirements - is usually the better choice.

      - The lack of PowerShell-friendliness starts with PowerShell's lack of proper support for NuGet packages, requiring extra effort to download and reference the [EPPlus NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75537273/45375) for background information.
  - It:

    - collects the (data) rows of interest as `[OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeRow]` instances in an output array for further processing; the cells of each such row can be enumerated via the `.Range` property, and each enumerated cell has a `.Value` property.
    - does *not* create PowerShell friendly [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject) instances, with properties named for the header cells, the way that `Import-Excel` from the `ImportExcel` does.
    - does *not* attempt to *update the spreadsheet itself*, i.e. it doesn't remove the rows you want to skip (omit).
    - The **[other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77796194/45375)** shows an **`ImportExcel`-based solution** that performs these tasks.

```bash
# Specify the license type (required in v5+ of EPPlus)
$env:EPPlusLicenseContext = 'NonCommercial'

# Load the EPPlus assembly.
Add-Type -LiteralPath "/home/lokesh/EPPlus.dll"  # Replace with the path to your EPPlus.dll file

# The file path of the workbook to open.
$filePath = "/home/lokesh/NSG_Rules.xlsx"

# Create an Excel package object and load the workbook file.
# Convert-Path ensures that a *full path* is passed, which is required in
# .NET calls, given that .NET's working dir. usually differs from PowerShell's.
$excelPackage = 
  [OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage]::new((Convert-Path -LiteralPath $filePath))

# Get the first worksheet from the Excel package
$worksheet = $excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[0]

# Iterate over all rows that have cells with content and/or formatting
# and collect the data rows of interest.
$headerProcessed = $false
[array] $rowsOfInterest = 
  foreach ($row in $worksheet.Rows) { # process each row
    $rowCellCount = 0; $skipRow = $false
    foreach ($cell in $row.Range) { # process each cell in a row
      ++$rowCellCount
      if (-not $headerProcessed) { continue } # header row: just count the cells.
      # data row: check for a background color of interest. 
      $skipRow = $cell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb -in 'FFFFFF00', 'FFA9A9A9'  
      if ($skipRow) { break }
    }
    if (-not $headerProcessed) { 
      # header row: Save the count of cells in the header row (assumed to be the first one),
      # i.e. the count of columns
      $headerRowCellCount = $rowCellCount
      $headerProcessed = $true
      continue
    } 
    # data row: Also check if not all cells in the rows had values.
    $skipRow = $skipRow -or $rowCellCount -lt $headerRowCellCount
    if (-not $skipRow) {
      $row # output
    }
  }

# $rowsOfInterest is now an array of [OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeRow] instances
# containing only those data rows that neither have empty cells nor
# cells with the specified background colors.

# Sample output: Print the address and value of the cells in these rows.
$rowsOfInterest.Range | Select-Object Address, Value
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the [EPPlus-only solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77795214/45375), this is an **[`ImportExcel`](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)-based solution**, which improves on the former in the following ways:

- Since `ImportExcel` *wraps* the EPPlus library and is distributed as a PowerShell [module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules), installation is as simple as `Install-Module ImportExcel -Scope CurrentUser`, for instance.

  - Note: As discussed in the other answer, `ImportExcel` wraps an *old* version of the EPPlus library for licensing reasons. This actually makes the code that analyzes the spreadsheet more cumbersome, because the spreadsheet objects don't have a `.Rows` property for row-by-row processing and the `.Cells` property (cell-by-cell processing) must be used instead.
- It *modifies* the spreadsheet to *delete* the unwanted rows.

  - Note: To be safe, the modifications aren't *saved* in the code below, but you can do so by removing the `-NoSafe` switch from the `Close-ExcelPackage` call.
- It then uses `Import-Excel` to parse the remaining rows - i.e. only those of interest - into PowerShell-friendly [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject) instances reflecting the spreadsheet rows in an OO fashion, with properties named for the header cells.

```bash
$path = '/home/lokesh/NSG_Rules.xlsx'

# Open the Excel package (workbook) and obtain a reference to its
# first worksheet.
$pkg = Open-ExcelPackage $path
$ws = $pkg.Workbook.Worksheets[1]

$rowsToDeleteIndices = [System.Collections.Generic.List[int]] @()

$startRow = 0; $headerColCount = $colCount = 0; $prevRow = 0; $prevSkippedRow = 0
foreach ($cell in $ws.Cells) { # enumerate all cells with values and/or formatting
  $currRow = $cell.Start.Row
  # Header row: Only count the number of cells.
  if ($startRow -eq 0) { $startRow = $prevRow = $currRow }
  if ($currRow -eq $startRow) { ++$headerColCount; continue }
  # Data row:
  if ($currRow -ne $prevRow) { # new data row reached
    # If the previous row wasn't the header row and didn't have all cells filled, skipt it too
    # (unless already skipped)
    if ($prevRow -ne $startRow -and $colCount -ne $headerColCount -and $prevRow -ne $prevSkippedRow) { 
      $rowsToDeleteIndices.Add($prevRow)
      $prevSkippedRow = $prevRow
    }
    $colCount = 1
    $prevRow = $currRow
  } else {
    ++$colCount
  }
  # If the current row has already been skipped, ignore its remaining cells.
  if ($currRow -eq $prevSkippedRow) { continue }
  # Skip any row that has a cell with the specified background colors.
  if ($cell.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb -in 'FFFFFF00', 'FFA9A9A9') {
    $rowsToDeleteIndices.Add($currRow)
    $prevSkippedRow = $currRow
  }
}
# If the *last* row was incomplete, skip it too.
if ($currRow -ne $prevSkippedRow -and $colCount -ne $headerColCount) {
  $rowsToDeleteIndices.Add($currRow)
}

# Now delete the unwanted rows from the spreadsheet.
$i = 0
$rowsToDeleteIndices | ForEach-Object { $ws.DeleteRow($_ + $i--) }

# Now use Import-Excel to parse the remaining rows - i.e. only the
# ones of interest - as PowerShell-friendly [pscsutomobject] instances.
# (The first worksheet is targeted by default.)
$rowsOfInterest = 
  Import-Excel -ExcelPackage $pkg

# Close the package.
# Note:
#  To also save the modified workbook, omit -NoSave
Close-ExcelPackage $pkg -NoSave

# Display the results.
$rowsOfInterest | Format-Table
```