# What is the difference between PsResourceGet, Winget and PackageManagement?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the hang of administering system wide software and administering resources (modules, script) for PowerShell. There is some confusion on what PowerShell component to use and would like some help in understanding what is intended for what.

After searching around and still not understanding, I learnt the hard way that [PSResourceGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.psresourceget/about/about_psresourceget?view=powershellget-3.x) is actually just a renamed module of [PowerShellGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/?view=powershellget-3.x). It is for discovering and installing PowerShell only resources such as PowerShell modules.

On the other hand, [Winget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/package-manager/winget/) and its unreleased PowerShell module, [Microsoft.WinGet.Client](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.WinGet.Client/1.6.3133.0) is for installing windows software such as Visual Studio Code, WinRrar etc. Then in this context, what is the [Package Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/?view=powershellget-2.x) component for?

My assumption is that is seems to do a mix of what winget, PsResourceGet seem to do. Does that mean I can just ditch both winget and PsResourceGet and just stick with Package Management?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The `PowerShellGet` module (which provides the `Install-Module` cmdlet) and the module it depends on, `PackageManagement` (formerly known as OneGet), are *no longer actively developed*.
- [`Microsoft.PowerShell.PSResourceGet`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSResourceGet) (formerly known as PowerShellGet v3) is the actively developed *successor* to `PowerShellGet` and therefore, as you note, limited to *PowerShell* resources. The successor to the `Install-Module` cmdlet is `Install-PSResource`.
- You can think of the [Windows Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/), whose CLI is [`winget.exe`](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli), as effectively succeeding `PackageManagement`:

  - What `winget.exe` *doesn't* cover that `PackageManagement` did is *NuGet* packages.

    - However, *PowerShell lacks proper support for direct consumption of NuGet packages anyway* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75537273/45375).
  - `winget.exe`, as an external executable, is by definition not very PowerShell-friendly.

    - The module you mention, [`Microsoft.WinGet.Client`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.WinGet.Client), is meant to provide equivalent functionality in a PowerShell-friendly manner, but, as of this writing, no stable version has been released (the description on the linked page states "this module is not marked as prerelease but should be treated as such"), and the latest version as of this writing, v1.6.3133.0, *doesn't even work* in PowerShell 7.4.1. Generally, development of this module seems to be *low-priority*: see [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/discussions/3182#discussioncomment-5755357).

      - (There is a [third-party module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WinGet) that is implemented as a `PackageManagement` provider, but given the [obsolescent status](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget#announcement) of the latter, it is probably a dead end; see below for an alternative).
- There is a third-party successor to `PackageManagement`, which the [`PackageManagement` "retirement" announcement](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget#announcement) links to:

  - [`AnyPackage`](https://github.com/anypackage/anypackage), like `PackageManagement`, uses a *provider model* (though note that it does *not* support providers created *for `PackageManagement`*), and one of the providers is [for WinGet](https://github.com/anypackage/winget), which uses the `winget.exe` CLI behind the scenes, whose output is parsed into objects assisted by the [`Crescendo` module](https://github.com/PowerShell/Crescendo).
    As of this writing, the linked provider's page includes the following [**caveats**](https://github.com/anypackage/winget?tab=readme-ov-file#known-issues) (extra emphasis added; lightly edited):
  - > WinGet does not currently have an official module available on the PowerShell Gallery, therefore this provider currently depends on a Crescendo module that is a best-effort attempt at parsing WinGet's output. Due to WinGet still being heavily in development, its output patterns fluctuate regularly, making a Crescendo-based implementation very brittle. As such, currently this provider **should not be used in production scenarios**.
  - > Due to WinGet's ambiguous search behavior and the risks of unintended outcomes, this provider **only allows searching of packages on remote repositories by exact package ID**. Fuzzy searches and searches by moniker, display name, and tag are not supported.