# Restore nuget packages with dependencies

Tags: c#, powershell, nuget, nuget-package

I am faced with a complicated task, I want to load an assembly from the Nuget packages folder and use it in my PowerShell script. But each package contains its own dlls (and it is logical).
[image]

How can I upload or place all dlls with their dependencies in one folder by Nuget or other Powershell tools?

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50004706/45375) helps.